# $ does not resolve to the root context from within a helm template

Tags: kubernetes-helm

I'm trying to iterate over `.Files.Glob` in a Helm template. I pass a string value into the template, so I've swapped over to using `$.Files.Glob` to refer back to the root context. However I get an error saying that there's no field "Files" on type string.

The error:

```
error calling include: template: example/templates/_helpers.tpl:77:29: executing "apiMounts" at <$.Files.Glob>: can't evaluate field Files in type string
```

The template:

```
{{- define "apiMounts" -}}
{{- range $path, $_ := $.Files.Glob . }}
{{- $name := (base $path) }}
- name: specs
  mountPath: {{ printf "/etc/apis/%s" $name }}
  subPath: {{ sha256sum $name }}
{{- end }}
{{- end }}
```

How I'm using the template (deployment):

```
          volumeMounts:
            {{- include "apiMounts" "common/**.json" | indent 12 }}
            {{- include "apiMounts" "v1/**.json" | indent 12 }}
```

According to the [Helm documentation](https://helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/variables/), `$` should always refer back to the root context, but in this case it seems to still be referring to the string that I've passed to the template.

> However, there is one variable that is always global - `$` - this variable will always point to the root context. This can be very useful when you are looping in a range and you need to know the chart's release name.

How can I used `.Files.Glob` in this template, while still passing in the string value?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The value you pass into the include function becomes the root context.

You can get the original root context inside the template function by passing in a list which includes it and your argument:

```
{{- include "apiMounts" (list $ "common/**.json") | indent 12 }}
```

Inside your template function, restore the "root" context and grab your argument:

```
{{- define "apiMounts" -}}
{{- $ := index . 0 }}
{{- $arg := index . 1 }}
{{- range $path, $_ := $.Files.Glob $arg }}
...
```

Comment: That was it, thanks. I didn't realize that the value passed into the include becomes the root.

Comment: Very helpful answer, thank you!